# Dailymotion PHP stream url not working

Tags: dailymotion-api

I have integrated PHP SDK of Dailymotion ( https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-php ) in my website.

I have fetched stream_h264_hq_url by this api ( both Local and Live ). It's woks fine in Local Apache but didn't work in live website.

Comment: I my live website, Dailymotion API gives me an improper URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `stream_*_url` fields have security restrictions as explained in the documentation (https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-stream_h264_hq_url-field):

> Without an access token this field contains null, the Dailymotion user associated with the access token must be the owner of the video. This field is rate limited. The returned url is secured: it can only be consumed by the user who made the query and it expires after a certain time.

Hence, the returned url is signed so it can only be consumed by the machine which did the API call. In other words, only your server, that performed the API call, can read the stream.

Comment: Then how can i assign the stream url to my custom HTML5 video tag. Is it possible ?.

My need is look like this

$result = $api->get(
'/video/x2pw9ox',
array('fields' => array('id', 'title', 'owner','stream_h264_hq_url'))
);

<video width="400" controls>
<source src="<?php echo $result ['stream_h264_hq_url'] ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: I have successfully done by the same way with Dailymotion Cloud ( CloudKey.php ) . But doesn't Dailymotion.php

Comment: you have to use the dailymotion player to play videos hosted on our platform. For example, you can request the embed_html field (https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-embed_html-field) to obtain the embed code. Other idea: you can use the javascript sdk (https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-javascript) to play videos and interact with the player.

Comment: It gives me iframe. I have my own custom skin video player so I need only mp4 URL. No problem i will renew the account in Dailymotion Cloud. This issue not in CloudKey.php